# zcat pipe to grep

Tags: unix, grep, zcat

```
ls -ltr|grep 'Mar  4'| awk '{print $9 }'|zcat -fq |grep  12345
```

I want to find all files modified on a certain date and then zcat them and search the fiels for a number string.

the above doesn't work because it searches the file name for the string not the file itself.

Any help?

M

Answer (score 2):

Use `xargs` to run the grep on the filenames output by awk:

```
ls -ltr | grep 'Mar 4' | awk '{print 9}' | xargs zcat -fq | grep 12345
```

Or, I guess, run the rest of the pipe from awk itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `find` instead. And/or `xargs`.

Answer (score 1):

If I read your command line correctly, its zcat that is trying to unpack the filenames instead of their content. Use xargs to solve this:

```
ls -ltr|grep 'Mar  4'| awk '{print $9 }'|xargs zcat -fq |grep  12345
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the fine answers about using `xargs` or `find`, you can also get rid of an extra process by eliminating `zcat` and piping to `zgrep` or `grep -Z` instead.

Comment: On my system (OS X) grep -Z doesn't do what you appear to think it does.

Comment: Apparently not on the Linux I have handy, either. Oops. zgrep is the better choice, then.